# How much longer will Worldbuilding be beta?

Tags: discussion

It seems to me that Worldbuilding is long overdue from becoming fully matured member of the Stackexchange network, especially now that all of the criteria is "excellent".

Anyone heard if it is going to happen?

Comment: Well 6 months have now passed, any update?

Comment: I don't have updates, but [that answer on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239949/285933) might indicate that nothing will probably happen soon. Last sites needed 2 years in beta. We haven't even reach the 1st anniversary.

Comment: OK, thanks, I have accepted the duplicate flag.

Comment: Another way to see that, is on [Area51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=beta). Some sites have spent more than 1500 days in beta so far. And some like [Code Review](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11464/code-review) or [Japanese](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7526/japanese-language) have reasonable stats.

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere recently that StackExchange has changed its policies about smaller but stable communities being in perma-beta. They assumed that a community had to be big to be stable (which clearly isn't true for Worldbuilding).  For the life of me, I can't find the article I read or what their plans were for the smaller, stable communities.

Comment: I believe you are talking about this article: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites

Comment: Yep, that's the one.